# How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I am trying to deserialize some JSON that contains a value that is sometimes an array, and sometimes a single item.  How can I do this with [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json) and [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer)?  (This question is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182) for Json.NET by [Robert McLaws](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403765/robert-mclaws).)

I have received the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337966815,
    "category": [
      "newuser",
      "transactional"
    ],
    "event": "open"
  },
  {
    "email": "jane.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337966815,
    "category": "olduser",
    "event": "open"
  }
]
```

And I want to deserialize it to a list of the following type:

```
class Item
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }

    public List<string> Category { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following code:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};
var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Item>>(json, options);
```

However, when I do I get the following exception:

> ```
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: > $[1].category | LineNumber: 13 | BytePositionInLine: 25.
>    at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
>    at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.Read(JsonTokenType tokenType, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
>    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
>    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
>    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> ```

The exception occurs because the value of `"category"` is sometimes a single string, and sometimes an array of strings.  How can I deserialize such a property with `System.Text.Json`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997172/3744182) by [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers) and [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771970/3744182) to *[How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182)*, you can create a generic [`JsonConverter<List<T>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1) that checks whether the incoming JSON value is an array, and if not, deserializes an item of type `T` and returns the item wrapped in an appropriate list.  Even better, you can create a [`JsonConverterFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterfactory) that manufactures such a converter *for all list types `List<T>`* encountered in your serialization graph.

First, define the following converter and converter factory:

```
public class SingleOrArrayConverter<TItem> : SingleOrArrayConverter<List<TItem>, TItem>
{
    public SingleOrArrayConverter() : this(true) { }
    public SingleOrArrayConverter(bool canWrite) : base(canWrite) { }
}

public class SingleOrArrayConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public bool CanWrite { get; }

    public SingleOrArrayConverterFactory() : this(true) { }

    public SingleOrArrayConverterFactory(bool canWrite) => CanWrite = canWrite;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        var itemType = GetItemType(typeToConvert);
        if (itemType == null)
            return false;
        if (itemType != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(itemType))
            return false;
        if (typeToConvert.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) == null || typeToConvert.IsValueType)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var itemType = GetItemType(typeToConvert);
        var converterType = typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<,>).MakeGenericType(typeToConvert, itemType);
        return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converterType, new object [] { CanWrite });
    }

    static Type GetItemType(Type type)
    {
        // Quick reject for performance
        if (type.IsPrimitive || type.IsArray || type == typeof(string))
            return null;
        while (type != null)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                var genType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (genType == typeof(List<>))
                    return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                // Add here other generic collection types as required, e.g. HashSet<> or ObservableCollection<> or etc.
            }
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class SingleOrArrayConverter<TCollection, TItem> : JsonConverter<TCollection> where TCollection : class, ICollection<TItem>, new()
{
    public SingleOrArrayConverter() : this(true) { }
    public SingleOrArrayConverter(bool canWrite) => CanWrite = canWrite;

    public bool CanWrite { get; }

    public override TCollection Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonTokenType.Null:
                return null;
            case JsonTokenType.StartArray:
                var list = new TCollection();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                        break;
                    list.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TItem>(ref reader, options));
                }
                return list;
            default:
                return new TCollection { JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TItem>(ref reader, options) };
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (CanWrite && value.Count == 1)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.First(), options);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in value)
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, item, options);
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the the converter factory to [`JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.converters?System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_Converters) before deserialization:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new SingleOrArrayConverterFactory() },
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};
var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Item>>(json, options);
```

Or add a specific converter either to options or to your data model directly using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute):

```
class Item
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<string>))]
    public List<string> Category { get; set; }
}
```

If your data model uses some other type of collection, say `ObservableCollection<string>`, you can apply a lower level converter `SingleOrArrayConverter<TCollection, TItem>` as follows:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<ObservableCollection<string>, string>))]
    public ObservableCollection<string> Category { get; set; }
```

Notes:

- If you want the converter(s) to apply only during deserialization, pass `canWrite: false` to the parameterized constructor:

  ```
  Converters = { new SingleOrArrayConverterFactory(canWrite: false) }
  ```

  The converter will still get used, but will unconditionally generate a default serialization.
- The converter is not implemented for jagged `2d` or `nD` collections such as `List<List<string>>`.  It is also not implemented for arrays and read-only collections.
- According to *[Serializer support for easier object and collection converters #1562](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1562#issue-547760443)*, because [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=netcore-3.1) lacks an async `Read()` method,

  > A limitation of the existing [JsonConverter] model is that it must "read-ahead" during deserialization to fully populate the buffer up to the end up the current JSON level. This read-ahead only occurs when the **async+stream** `JsonSerializer` deserialize methods are called and only when the current JSON for that converter starts with a StartArray or StartObject token.

  Thus using this converter to deserialize potentially very large arrays may have a negative performance impact.

  As discussed in the same thread, the converter API may get redesigned in System.Text.Json - 5.0 to fully support `async` deserialization by converters for arrays and object, implying that this converter may benefit from being rewritten when [.NET 5](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md) (no longer labeled with "Core") is eventually released.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GWsJ60).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the first working answer I've found that uses pure JSON.Net. You saved me hours of converting my project to Newtonsoft.

Comment: This should be in the core library.  Should be as easy as decorating the property.

Comment: This was what I needed, by the way, does it already support async?

Comment: @Angelru - As of .NET 7 `JsonConverter` still doesn't have an async method; the JSON still gets preloaded before the call to `Read()`.  It will work just fine, but use more memory because of buffering.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it is use 'object' type. See example below

```
    public class Example
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Event { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("category")]
        public object CategoryObjectOrArray { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<string> Category
        {
            get
            {
                if (CategoryObjectOrArray is JsonElement element)
                {
                    switch (element.ValueKind)
                    {
                        case JsonValueKind.Array:
                            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(element.GetRawText());
                        case JsonValueKind.String:
                            return new List<string> { element.GetString() };
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution allows `CategoryObjectOrArray` to be of any type, however I'd like to use compile-time typing to restrict `Category` to be zero, one or more strings, and nothing else.