# Convert Json string to a different type

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have an object like this

```
"maqVeicEquip": 
{
    "item": 
    {
        "tipoMaq": "03",
        "marca": "DAF",
        "idadeMediaFrota": "1",
        "quantidade": "2",
        "indOnus": "true",
        "valorMedio": "0.00",
        "outrasInformacoes": "XF105 FTT510 - BCO PACCAR",
        "percPropriedade": "100.00"
    }
}
```

I can't deserialize it because the `item` is a `List<>`. You guys know some way to force deserialize `item` as a `List<Item>`?

Here is my class

```
public class MaqVeicEquip
{
    public List<Item> item { get; set; }
    
    public class Item
    {
        public string tipoMaq { get; set; }
        public string marca { get; set; }
        public string idadeMediaFrota { get; set; }
        public string quantidade { get; set; }
        public string indOnus { get; set; }
        public string valorMedio { get; set; }
        public string outrasInformacoes { get; set; }
        public string percPropriedade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would your `maqVeicEquip` property contain multiple items in the JSON?

Comment: Why not just use another type which will correctly represent the JSON structure?

Comment: Also you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77008819/2501279) if your json is dynamic (i.e. `item` can be either single item or an array).

Comment: Instead of combining the two steps, why not de-serialize into the structure that the data already uses and then re-shape that structure into your domain as needed?

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Newtonsoft.Json for serialisation, you can

a) Define a custom converter as follows (example adapted from [this post by Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997172/14868997)):

```
public class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<T> list = (List<T>)value;
        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, list[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
        }
    }
}
```

b) Apply a custom converter to the property of your class:

```
public class MaqVeicEquip
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<Item>))]
    public List<Item> item { get; set; }

    public class Item
    {
        public string tipoMaq { get; set; }
        public string marca { get; set; }
        public string idadeMediaFrota { get; set; }
        public string quantidade { get; set; }
        public string indOnus { get; set; }
        public string valorMedio { get; set; }
        public string outrasInformacoes { get; set; }
        public string percPropriedade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

c) Deserialise the JSON to an object:

```
var str = @"
{
    ""item"": 
    {
        ""tipoMaq"": ""03"",
        ""marca"": ""DAF"",
        ""idadeMediaFrota"": ""1"",
        ""quantidade"": ""2"",
        ""indOnus"": ""true"",
        ""valorMedio"": ""0.00"",
        ""outrasInformacoes"": ""XF105 FTT510 - BCO PACCAR"",
        ""percPropriedade"": ""100.00""
    }
}
";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MaqVeicEquip>(str);
```

Now, the obj should consist of the following data:

[image]

Hope this helps or at least pushes you in a good direction.

Answer (score -2):

thank you guys,
i changed from

```
public List<Item> item { get; set; }
```

to

```
public object item { get; set; }
```

and solve the issue.
using **dynamic** as type also solve the issue.

Comment: While the approach of using `object`or `dynamic offers` a quick and simple way to handle the problem, it has potential pitfalls and might not be suitable for all scenarios. Using the custom converter provides more robustness and clarity, albeit with a bit more setup. The right approach largely depends on the specific requirements of the project.

Answer (score -3):

You can not change the rules of deserialization. An object will deserialize to an object & an array/list will deserialize to `List<Item>`. So, I would suggest you declare the `Item` as an `Object` rather than a `List<Item>`. However, you may create a read-only property that may convert the `Item` `Object` to `List<Item>` and finally return `List<Item>`.